# Intersection observer API scroll aware navigation

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, intersection-observer

I am trying to use the intersection observer to create something like the website link below, the whole aim is to recreate that the sticky boxes that serve as a navigation to each section, my thought process for this relates to the navigation bar on changing the active section when it comes in, a link to my codepen is attached an image also showing what I'm trying to achieve on the main site I got the idea from with a link to the site,
Codepen: https://codepen.io/thatfemicode/pen/JjWRNoZ
Sitelink: https://olaolu.dev/

Javascript

```
 const changeNav = (entries, observer) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        // verify the element is intersecting
        if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.55) {
          // remove old active class
          document.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
          // get id of the intersecting section
          var id = entry.target.getAttribute("id");
          // find matching link & add appropriate class
          var newLink = document
            .querySelector(`[href="#${id}"]`)
            .classList.add("active");
        }
      });
    };
    
    // init the observer
    const options = {
      threshold: 0.55,
    };
    
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(changeNav, options);
    
    // target the elements to be observed
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
    sections.forEach((section) => {
      observer.observe(section);
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to fix some error?

Comment: No, basically I'm trying to create the fixed boxes that act as each boxes, I wish I could have added an image to illustrate what I'm trying to do, on my codepen demo, I used the intersection observer to change the active class when a section enters into the viewport, that's what I'm trying to achieve also with the fixed boxes, when a section enters into the codepen the box with that section id changes, if you look at the bottom right of the page, notice the actions when you scroll down on the site https://olaolu.dev/ this site here. @lissettdm

Answer (score 1):

change in that script the newLink line to:

```
var newLink = document.querySelector('[href="#'+id+'"]').classList.add('active');
```